# Running LAN WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, sockets, ssl, https

I'm trying to create a client-server app where the server runs on the user's machine. I'm looking into either using WCF or Sockets but I have a couple of questions.

I'd like to use WCF but it seems that the user needs admin rights in order to launch the service. Would the user need admin rights if the WCF service was running within a managed application (e.g. a Windows Service)? With sockets it seems that admin rights isn't required to open the relevant port.

How would HTTPS security work in WCF? Since this is a LAN program (user talking from client to their own machine), do I need to purchase a certificate and install it on their machines? I'd rather avoid this if possible as the data being transferred isn't sensitive. Would this be the same if I use SSLStream for sockets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of questions, :), so very short answer on part of them:

1. You can host WCF even in console application. Windows Services may not require admin properties to be installed on pc.
2. For HTTPS - you does not have to buy certificate, you can crate your own - there are a lot of examples in the net. But - if your data is not sensitive - you can probably use simple http.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If the user runs the console application would that mean they can run the WCF service without admin rights (not just installation)? My user needs to log in once (just to make sure that someone else on the network can't access the same server on their behalf) but the rest of the transactions are not sensitive.

Comment: Wcf itself does not requore adminrights, so yes. For "login once" - certificate will not help, since you need asority that will valisate it. Maybe you can allow your service for specific os user instead?

Comment: Unfortunately the client isn't tied to the OS user as it may be an iPhone/Android device. Is there a better way, or is it pretty much impossible as anyone could just do a replay attack even if the username/password is sent encrypted?

Comment: If you want ti send only user and pwd encrypted, you need not ssl. Tske s look pn wcf security.